# What does the starmode mean for a ethernet interface?

Tags: linux, network-adapter

I find at least there are two start mode of an ethernet interface, on boot and auto. What is the difference between the two? Where I can find a formal document that covers this topic?

Comment: You missed some things.

Comment: Please explain which distribution you're using and where you set this mode. I believe you're referring to initialization scripts which are not standardized across distros.

Comment: I'm using SUSE11, and you can find STARTMODE in /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcg-eth0, for example

Answer (score 1):

As other comments have stated, network configuration differs between Linux distribution, but normally `onboot` or `static` in the configuration file is used for setting up a static interface configuration whereas `auto` defers the configuration which will then be performed by a DHCP client program like *dhclient* or *NetworkManager*.